# Django Ldap Autentication only works with DN_TEMPLATE

Tags: django, python-3.x, ldap, django-auth-ldap

trying to get my Django authentication work with an LDAP server but I cannot login, I've managed to do it using [forumsys test LDAP server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) using AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE, but adding both ou with LDAPSearchUnion (what I will need in my real project) it only shows "incorrect username/password" (my message in case of failed login)

Here's my settings.py:

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(
    LDAPSearch("ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com",
           ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)"),
    LDAPSearch("ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com",
           ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)"),
)

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    'first_name': 'givenName',
    'last_name': 'sn',
    'email': 'mail',
}
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
)
```

Views.py:

```
def login_page(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect("list")
context = {
    'form': LoginForm,
}
if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('list')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Wrong username or password')
            return redirect("login")
return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

Does anyone know what could I be doing wrong?

EDIT

I managed to do it by using this:

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=dc=example,dc=com", 
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

But the idea is to add an OU (for example scientists) so only scientists can log in into the app.